# specifying stdout by modifying an input string with cwl

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, yaml

I want to write a simple command wrapper using cwl (common workflow language). I want to do the following for example:

```
wc input.txt > input.txt.wc
wc some_folder/some_other_input > some_folder/some_other_input.wc
```

So, basically I want the code to put .wc after the input file name and use it as the output file name. I wrote the following code but it didn't work. (see below error message). Anyone has an idea how to fix it?

**wc2.cwl**

```
cwlVersion: cwl:draft-3
class: CommandLineTool
baseCommand: wc
inputs:
  - id: inputfile
    type: File
    inputBinding:
      position: 1
  - id: outfilename
    type: string
      inputBinding:
        valueFrom: ${ $(inputs.inputfile.path) + '.wc' }
outputs:
  - id: outputfile
    type: File
    outputBinding:
      glob: $(inputs.outfilename)
stdout: $(inputs.outfilename)
```

**wc2-job1.yml**

```
inputfile:
  class: File
  path: input.txt
```

**Run**

```
$ cwl-runner wc2.cwl wc2-job1.yml
/home/ec2-user/venv/cwl/bin/cwl-runner 1.0.20160504183010
I'm sorry, I couldn't load this CWL file, try again with --debug for more information.
mapping values are not allowed here
  in "file:///home/ec2-user/cwl.examples/hello.workflow2/wc2.cwl", line 11, column 19
```

Answer (score 0):

In `CWL` inputs you have to define the parameters which will appear in the created command line. `wc` stream to the standards output, then there is no need to specify `outfilename` in your inputs. Check `man wc` to display all the `wc` parameters.

This is a solution that you can use, but I don't think is the perfect one!

**wc2.cwl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env cwl-runner
cwlVersion: cwl:draft-3
class: CommandLineTool
baseCommand: wc
requirements:
  - class: InlineJavascriptRequirement

stdout: $(inputs.inputfile.path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '') + '.wc')
inputs:
  - id: inputfile
    type: File
    inputBinding:
      position: 1
outputs:
  - id: outputfile
    type: File
    outputBinding:
      glob: $(inputs.inputfile.path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '') + '.wc')
```

Answer (score 0):

stdout: $(inputs.outfilename)
to be,
stdout: $(inputs['outfilename'])

Comment: Please add explaination to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Common Workflow Language User Guide: Capturing Standard Output](https://www.commonwl.org/user_guide/05-stdout/)
and examples listed in https://www.commonwl.org/v1.0/CommandLineTool.html#stdout,
to specify a filename for the capture of standard out, you define `stdout: filename` and `outputs: type: stdout`:

**wc2.cwl**

```
cwlVersion: cwl:v1.0
class: CommandLineTool
baseCommand: wc
inputs:
  - id: inputfile
    type: File
    inputBinding:
      position: 1
outputs:
  - id: outputfile
    type: stdout
stdout: $(inputs.inputfile.basename).wc
```